# Another "fk_name ' ' is not a foreignkey to" problem [Python/Django]

Tags: python-3.x, django

please don't judge with my question. I tried every suggestion here but still no luck.

here's my code ---

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import candidates_info, address

class addressInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model = address
  fk_name = 'id'

@admin.register(candidates_info)
  class candidates_infoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  fields =['last_name', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'moniker']
  inlines = [addressInline]
```

models.py

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class candidates_info (models.Model):
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  #position = models.ForeignKey('positions', db_column='position_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
  #birth_date = models.ForeignKey('birthdate', db_column='date_of_birth_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
  #contact_info = models.ForeignKey('contact_info', db_column='contact_info_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  addr = models.ForeignKey('address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  moniker = models.CharField(max_length=35)
  #party = models.ForeignKey('political_parties', db_column='political_parties_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
  registration_dt = models.DateTimeField('date registered')

class address(models.Model):    
  lot_no = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
  block_no = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
```

note: the codes commented out (#) are part of my code in models.py which I temporarily disabled as part of my code to see if it's conflicting with the declaration of foreignKey.

and another thing, tried declaring and undeclaring fk_name on admin.py but still no luck. Please help guys. Been stock here for a few days now. I can't seem to find the bug.

TIA

btw.. here's the error from console ---

<class 'votenow.admin.addressInline'>: (admin.E202) fk_name 'id' is not a ForeignKey to 'votenow.candidates_info'.

Answer (score 0):

Change your models to include a Foriegnkey field with address

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class candidates_info (models.Model):
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  #position = models.ForeignKey('positions', db_column='position_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
  #birth_date = models.ForeignKey('birthdate', db_column='date_of_birth_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
  #contact_info = models.ForeignKey('contact_info', db_column='contact_info_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  addr = models.ForeignKey('address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  moniker = models.CharField(max_length=35)
  #party = models.ForeignKey('political_parties', db_column='political_parties_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
  registration_dt = models.DateTimeField('date registered')
  address =odels.ForeignKey(
        Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Address(models.Model):    
  lot_no = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
  block_no = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=0)
```

Comment: I already did didn't I? with the "addr = models.ForeignKey('address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)" Can you please elaborate more...